# laravel 8 API : upload multiple images and store them with postman

Tags: php, laravel, api, polymorphism

i'm building an API with laravel 8 . i want to store image or images for my posts with polymorphic relation between posts and images(because i have users and analysis tables too and i need image for them), but i can't upload and store images , when i send values in postman , like this :

[image]

as you can see , the images doesn't store in images table , and in result i can't see anything about images

i'm beginner and don't know about polymorphism so much , so i think my `store()` methode isn't correct.

this is my post table :

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->string('video')->nullable();
            $table->string('study_time');
            $table->integer('likes')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->nullable()->comment('status is 1 when a post is active and it is 0 otherwise.')->nullable();
            $table->text('tags')->nullable();


            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
         });
```

and my image table :

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('imageable_id');
            $table->string('imageable_type');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and the post model :

```
.
.
.
.
 public function image(){
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class , 'imageable');
    }
```

and my image model :

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'url'
    ];

    public function imageable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

and my store() method in postController :

```
 public function store(Request $request )
    {

        $post = new Post;
        $post->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->study_time = $request->get('study_time');
        $post->tags = $request->get('tags');
        $post->user_id = JWTAuth::user()->id;
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
        $post->tag($tags);


        if($request->hasfile('url'))
         {
            foreach($request->get('url') as $file)
            {
                $image = new Image;
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path().'/images/',$name);
                $post->photos()->save($image);
            }
         }

        $post->save();

        return response()->json($post , 201);

    }
```

also in postman in form-data , i enter images as file type

and in headers part i enter `Content-Type` with `multipart/form-data` value and

i don't know how to save images  , thank you for helping me.

Edit :

i change controller to this :

```
public function store(Request $request )
    {

        $post = new Post;
        $post->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
        $post->title = $request->get('title');
        $post->body = $request->get('body');
        $post->study_time = $request->get('study_time');
        $post->tags = $request->get('tags');
        $post->user_id = JWTAuth::user()->id;
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
        $post->tag($tags);

        $allowedfileExtension=['pdf','jpg','png'];
        $files = $request->file('fileName');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);
            if($check) {
                foreach($request->fileName as $mediaFiles) {

                    $url = $mediaFiles->store('public/images');

                    //store image file into directory and db
                    $image = new Image();
                    $image->url = $url;
                }
            }
            else {
                return response()->json(['invalid_file_format'], 422);
            }
        }


        $post->image()->save($image);
        $post->save();

        return response()->json($post , 201);
    }
```

and in postman i enter images with `url` field in body(form-data) :
[image]

so i have an error for my `foreach($files as $file)` what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Postman Demo]

Try Sending multiple image as shown in screenshot, you are sending images without name so request can not get which key holds the image, for sending multiple images use array (image[]) like in the screenshot and for sending single image you can use single field name like any other normal field name

Comment: so i entered a field `url[]` and select 3 images for uploading but it says : `rrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `

Comment: instead of `url[]` try `url`  and get file like `$url = $request->file('url');
foreach($url as $u){
    print_r($u->getClientOriginalName());
}`

Comment: [Click Here](https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-8-multiple-image-upload-via-api/) please refer this I tested it and it worked, in postman use `url` instead of `url[]`

Comment: i edited the question .. please check it again